# Mysql and php if time diff is under 1 minute

Tags: php, mysql, time

In mysql i have a lot of times and i show that with php in a table.

Now i need, 
if the times, i show, where WITHIN ONE MIN (the difference) i like to show the time in the (html) table red.

```
    Row    |    Time
     1     |  10:10:11
     2     |  10:12:01   <--- THIS RED
     3     |  10:12:50   <--- THIS RED
     4     |  10:14:12
```

Is there any way i can do that with php?
Now i use a simple mysql query. select .... from ....

I am grateful for everything

Comment: What would you want to show if say there were 4 records within one minute?

Comment: than all 4 records show red in html table, but its around 1000 times... and not all within 1 minute.

Comment: Use my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.`Row`,
       t1.`Time`,
       TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(t2.`Time`, t1.`Time`)) AS Diff,
       CASE WHEN (TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(t2.`Time`, t1.`Time`)) < 61 || TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(t1.`Time`, t3.`Time`)) < 61) THEN 'Red' ELSE 'Blue' END AS Color
FROM myTable t1
LEFT JOIN myTable t2
    ON t2.`Row` = t1.`Row`+1
LEFT JOIN myTable t3
    ON t3.`Row` = t1.`Row`-1
    ORDER BY t1.`Row` ASC
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcc695/1/0)

Please consider in my demo, I used VARCHAR for Time. But, it doesn't matter if you used any other types. Query works.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.Row,
       t1.Time,
       CASE WHEN t2.minute IS NOT NULL THEN 'Red' ELSE 'Black' END AS Color
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING(Time, 1, 2), SUBSTRING(Time, 4, 2)) AS minute
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY CONCAT(SUBSTRING(Time, 1, 2), SUBSTRING(Time, 4, 2))
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t2
    ON CONCAT(SUBSTRING(t1.Time, 1, 2), SUBSTRING(Time, 4, 2)) = t2.minute
```

Comment: @Mojtaba I updated my answer to only group minutes occurring at the same point in time otherwise.

Comment: maybe converting times to a timestamp and then calculate differences would help there

Comment: That's great. But, there is no year,month,day. just hour,minute and second

Comment: @Mojtaba So is your `Time` column actually a `varchar`?  This is bad practice, but in any case I have updated again.

Comment: The Time type doesn't matter for my query. It works anyway.